# Account.createUser call back is not working in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am developing an app with meteor js. I have created one meteor method for creating user. It's showing me following error:-

Accounts.createUser with callback not supported on the server yet.

here is my meteor method

how can i add callback in account.createUser?

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.methods({
        postForm:function(doc){
            var result = Accounts.createUser({
                username: doc.username,
                password: doc.password,
                email: doc.emails,
                profile: {
                    lastname: doc.lastname,
                    contact:doc.phoneNumber,
                    bdat:doc.bod,
                    address:doc.address
                }
            },function(){
                console.log('hello');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not just call `Accounts.createUser` on the client directly so you have the callback? The only reason I can think to put this into a method is so the user doesn't automatically sign in. The big downside here is that you are transmitting the user's password to the server.

Comment: i am using autoform for creating new user.. I'm unable to create hook for that form. It's showing me error of hooks is undefined.. So i have created meteor method..

Comment: I think you should reword your question to focus on the autoform issue since that appears to be the actual problem that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 7):

The "yet" in that error message is likely a mistake on the author's part. According to [the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser):

> On the server, [`Accounts.createUser`] returns the newly created user id.

This means that on the server-side, `Accounts.createUser` is essentially blocking: it waits for the user to be created, and then returns its newly generated id. So "the callback", in that case, is basically anything that follows your `createUser` statement. You get one value, the user's _id, which you can use to retrieve the inserted user with `Meteor.users.find()`. And you can catch thrown exceptions if you want to cover errors.

But as David Weldon said, you could basically do that using `Accounts.createUser()` on the client, which takes a callback. I guess it makes sense if you want to do something server-specific in the "callback" of that creation, but one may also argue that you could do a server method call just for that. (though it would call the server twice in that case, once for the creation, and once for the callback logic)

Answer (score 5):

I received exactly the same error message including the word "yet." My complete error message: `Exception while invoking method  Error: Accounts.createUser with callback not supported on the server yet.` Translate that error message as

> Hey, Developer, you big dummy, your method call doesn't handle both
>   response and error via callbacks, yet.  Please fix your code.

The issue for me was two fold.  Like you, I did not adequately account for callback error and response.  What that means is, if there is an error somewhere else in the chain of calls, that error WON'T get passed back to you, so you have no idea what's wrong.  Fix the call back code first.

```
Meteor.methods({
    postForm:function(doc){
        try {
          var result = Accounts.createUser({
              username: doc.username,
              password: doc.password,
              email: doc.emails,
              profile: {
                  lastname: doc.lastname,
                  contact:doc.phoneNumber,
                  bdat:doc.bod,
                  address:doc.address
              }
          });
          if(result){
              // are you using roles?
              // Roles.addUsersToRoles(result, doc.roles);  
              return result;
          }
        }
        catch(err){
            return err;
        }
    }
});
```

Hopefully this will 'fix' the `callback not supported` error message.  And at that time you should be able to see what is really causing your troubles.  In my case it was a faulty `Accounts.validateNewUser((user)` routine that I had copied from a tutorial and forgotten to update to match my data.

Oh, almost forgot... here's sample code to call the method from the client.

```
Meteor.call('postForm', newUser, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('postForm: Error: ', error);
    }
    if (response) {
        console.log('postForm: Response: ', response);
    }
});
```

Good luck with this.  Info offered here in case anybody gets the "yet" error!